# Why does Visual Studio 2019 recommend a switch expression instead of a switch statement?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, switch-expression

Visual Studio 2019 recommended converting a switch statement I had written to a [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) (both included below for context).

For a simple example such as this, is there any technical or performance advantage to writing it as an expression? Do the two versions compile differently for example?

**Statement**

```
switch(reason)
{
    case Reasons.Case1: return "string1";
    case Reasons.Case2: return "string2";
    default: throw new ArgumentException("Invalid argument");
}
```

**Expression**

```
return reason switch {
    Reasons.Case1 => "string1",
    Reasons.Case2 => "string2",
    _ => throw new ArgumentException("Invalid argument")
};
```

Comment: In your example I would say the only advantage is that the latter is less verbose and thereby more readable (once you get used to the new syntax). For extended usage one big advantage is that you can return a value directly from the `switch` - less procedural code.

Comment: It's more readable, I'd like to say

Comment: How does your research re technical switch statement vs expression pros & con apply? Because otherwise you are asking for SO content to be duplicated & you show no research.

Comment: While `case Reasons.Case1` is redundant, personally I much prefer `default:` written out than to have to intuit that `_ =>` means default... so it's a tradeoff in terms of readability to me, with the statement actually edging a bit ahead of the expression.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the example you give there's not a lot in it really. However, switch expressions are useful for declaring and initializing variables in one step. For example:

```
var description = reason switch 
{
    Reasons.Case1 => "string1",
    Reasons.Case2 => "string2",
    _ => throw new ArgumentException("Invalid argument")
};
```

Here we can declare and initialize `description` immediately. If we used a switch statement we'd have to say something like this:

```
string description = null;
switch(reason)
{
    case Reasons.Case1: description = "string1";
                        break;
    case Reasons.Case2: description = "string2";
                        break;
    default:            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid argument");
}
```

One downside of switch expressions at the moment (in VS2019 at least) is that you can't set a breakpoint on an individual condition, only the whole expression. However, with switch statements you can set a breakpoint on an individual case statement.

Comment: While it does look better than the usual switch, are there any benefits? Like, let's say, you call it a million times, will it be faster?

Comment: @Sheradil Chances are both versions will produce essentially identical IL anyway so I doubt there's a perf benefit.

Comment: The page [here](http://writeasync.net/?p=5758) shows a benchmark indicating that IfElse is slightly faster than Statement, and Expression is noticeably slower than both.  I have not run this myself.